# Migrate data from Excel to SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a lot of Excel and Access files. I need to create a new database and import these files into tables. How should I do this?

Comment: Please read the following article on how to ask a question on this site: http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Create a new database and then import your data from excel and access.

Comment: JNevill is likely suggesting the Data Import wizard, if you right click on a database, you can pick Tasks -> Import Data, and walk through a wizard that will create and run an SSIS package that imports the data.

Answer (score 1):

If this is a one time job, do it manually:

Copy the data from your source (right click or ctrl-c) table.

In SSMS, right click the table and click "Edit Top 200 Rows".
Select the space notated by a star (*) at the first empty row on the left.
Paste.

Or you can use SSIS and automate by setting a For Each Loop Container, expression being the file name(s) in a particular folder. I am assuming all of your files have the same columns, so you can map the same columns from SOURCE to DESTINATION.  This would be the quickest way, in my opinion.

http://help.pragmaticworks.com/dtsxchange/scr/FAQ%20-%20How%20to%20loop%20through%20files%20in%20a%20specified%20folder,%20load%20one%20by%20one%20and%20move%20to%20archive%20folder%20using%20SSIS.htm